# C library - generating a public header from a set of private headers

Tags: c, header-files

I have a set of internal header files for a C library. I'd like to generate a single public header containing a certain subset of declarations. An obvious solution that comes to mind is marking certain blocks with //EXPORT (by "block" I mean a sequence of non-blank lines). Then it is easy to put together a script to do the work.

Is there is a better and/or standard method?

EDIT. Here is a skeleton example:

```
/*foo.h*/
...
int foo();
...

/*foo.c*/
int foo()
{
...
}


/*bar.h*/
...
int bar();
...

/*bar.c*/
#include "foo.h"
int bar()
{
    foo();
...
}


/*my_lib_single_public.h*/
...
int foo();
int bar();
```

The modules foo and bar ideally do one thing and do it well (they can still be quite large and call a lot of stuff in other modules) and I'd like to emphasize this by keeping this internal structure. The whole thing is packaged as a library: my_lib.so + my_lib_single_public.h. What I want is to generate my_lib_single_public.h automatically so that I do not have to manually copy/paste the declarations.

Thanks

Comment: TBH, a "standard" solution would be to have a dedicated header file that represents your external API (rather than constructing one on the fly).

Comment: I undersand that. But I just want a way to keep that dedicated external header in sync with internal one's. Thinking SPOT principle on the level of interfaces.

Comment: What gets out of sync?  (Or more precisely, why is anything repeated/duplicated?)

Comment: Even if it is not a major API change it cold be something small like an added/removed typedef.

Comment: I guess what I'm hinting at is that those definitions should all be in the public header, and **only** there.  You shouldn't need to duplicate them in some other header.

Comment: I see... but this can mess up my "module structure" quite a bit.. I'd like every .c file to have a corresponding .h file, containing all the declarations (speaking of the internal structure of the library).

Comment: You may need to re-think that approach ;)

Comment: I agree with the recommendation to double check the need for this design. But I also know how to do it, if I understand your question correctly. You want to have a structured API, with a common block everybody sees when including and several special blocks, each of which should only be visible to certain "includers". I assume that such includers are code files, wich can be identified by pre-processor switches they define to identify themselves. Groups of includers can share the same identifier switch. I know this concept as "need-to-know-interfaces". Would that achieve your goal?

Comment: @lanskey I saw this in very old OSF-Motif as well as in modern Qt: C and C++ files which use "public" and "private" types. The declarations are put into .h and _private.h files (and possibly the private header files in separate include directories). Example: [QWidget on woboq](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp.html) In C++, this is often combined with the PIMPL idiom but I believe its not a must. Additionally in C, "opaque data" is used (as in glib), i.e. header provides pointer to incomplete struct which is "complete" in the resp. source only.

Comment: @Yunnosch this is a very cool technique, thanks. But I am not so concerned about the structure of the API, I only want to separate the private and public parts in a clean way, while preserving the INTERNAL structure of the library. Also, if at some point I see, that exporting some private function is beneficial to the library users, it would be nice to have a mechanism to do that without the risk of messing things up.

Comment: So I have misunderstood? OK. Can you make an example with the one file and the different "views"? I.e. three copies of the header, 1 the original, 2 seen as included from A and 3 seen as included from B. Did I at least understand correctly that you only want one file, to prevent unsynched editing of several files? Just try to edit your question so that even I cannot misunderstand... Use examples, and maybe sock-puppets.

Comment: I have a very similar question and haven't been able to find other advice on the internet. @lanskey did you ever come up with a sensible solution?